# mysql custom auto increment field with pre/suffix text

Tags: mysql, database

How can I make a field that has a ability to auto-incremented once successfully inserted.. Like XX00001, XX00002, XX00003, XX00004. Like that. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't. You format the output to whatever you like

Comment: Like how? Think you can provide some examples?

Comment: Or place the prefix/suffix in some other column and concatenate them upon retrieval.

Comment: I'm thinking something like that but my problem is what if I'll come to like this.. XX0001... XX00010, XX00011.. don't know how to solve that one. Think you can show some examples?

Comment: what is the behavior you want to have? XX00011 or XX0011? In other words do you need to have fixed length?

Comment: I have a 2-letter prefix followed by incremented 5-digit number. It would be a great help for me :)

Comment: Yes. A fixed length :)

Comment: I wrote some code for custom auto_increment values: 
http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2012/custom-auto-increment-values/
Just try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  prefix CHAR(2),
  number INT(5) ZEROFILL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (number)
);

INSERT INTO my_table (prefix) VALUES ('XX'), ('XX'), ('XX');

SELECT CONCAT(prefix, number) FROM my_table;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d79b7/1/0).

Comment: Such a great help. Very very much thank you!

Comment: @BoyPasmo: I didn't think about it before, but you can also set a `DEFAULT` value for `prefix` if so desired: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c21b2/1/0